# Checking if layer is visible in legend using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, legend

I want to be able to check if a layer is visible in the legend and if so then perform another operation - in python.  I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

I cannot find anywhere how to check if a layer is visible or not in the legend.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you mean the visibility of the layer in the Table Of Contents, once you get a reference to the layer, it has a `visible` attribute:

```
import arcpy

inMXD = "xyz.mxd"
lyrName = "layername"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inMXD)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0] #the first data frame
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyrName, df)[0]
if(lyr.visible):
    print(lyr.name + " is visible")
else:
    print(lyr.name + " is not visible")
```

If the visibility of the layer in the Legend does not match the visibility in the Table Of Contents, you can use [listLegendItemLayers ()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000041000000):

```
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
legendLayers = legend.listLegendItemLayers()

for idx in range(0, len(legendLayers)):
    legendLayer = legendLayers[idx]
    legendVisibility = legendLayer.visible
    if(legendVisibility == 0):
        print(legendLayer.name + " is not visible on the legend")
    else:
        print(legendLayer.name + " is visible on the legend")
```